# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import own package

Tags: python, pypi

I created a custom package to convert and rename images easily that ran properly when using it in TestPyPi but when I finally uploaded the dist to PyPi and installed it in my environment and tried to run it I get a ModuleFoundError.

This is my pipfreeze now:

> certifi==2020.6.20
> imgconvren==0.0.1
> Pillow==7.2.0

Pillow is part of my dependencies

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "test.py", line 1, in 
> import imgconvren
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imgconvren'

You can find my code [here](https://github.com/charlescsr/imgconvren)

Anything I'm missing here? I run Ubuntu with Anaconda for my envs.

Comment: try `import convren` not imgconvren

Comment: Ok that did the trick. Should I look to renaming the folder to imgconvren as well then?

Comment: Up to you really the name of the repo/packaged file needs not to match the package name